# Adobe ActionJson API is not working, for image conversion

Tags: image-processing, adobe, photoshop, tiff

I am submitting a request to convert images into TIFF format using the ActionJson API. I received a successful response with a status code of 200, and the URL for checking the conversion status is "https://image.adobe.io/pie/psdService/status/154bbeeb-872a-4699-a9d6-70ead2e87b66". However, when I check the status using this URL, it only returns "running," and the file doesn't seem to be uploading.

I am currently developing a Django application that accepts any image and converts it into TIFF format. These images are stored in an S3 bucket. To perform the conversion, I rely on the Adobe API (ActionJson).

My goal is to utilize the Adobe API (ActionJson) for converting images into the TIFF format.

I am currently developing a Django application that accepts any image and converts it into TIFF format. These images are stored in an S3 bucket. To perform the conversion, I rely on the Adobe API (ActionJson).

```
payload :- "{
"inputs": [
{
"storage": "external",
"href": "https://fileconversiontiff.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2023/08/25/IMG_20230825_153826.dng?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA33JFNCWOYFF7WHPX%2F20230911%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230911T123753Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=7c0ad245bafa545241e5dd7d7d005cfd9c9377ae1e459aae27b7c9f6f09782b2"
}
],
"options": {
"actionJSON": [
null
]
},
"outputs": [
{
"name": "test-122.tiff",
"storage": "external",
"href": "https://fileconversiontiff.s3.amazonaws.com/name.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA33JFNCWOYFF7WHPX%2F20230910%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230910T142856Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=37ac41c42e9d12032e5aa44a1bff138a6b9e39a3f1e7f51c05674e356d8bb3f6",
"type": "image/tiff"
}
]
}"
```